# Bluetooth Connection Issues Between Android and Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, networking, wireless-networking, android, bluetooth

I have a Windows 10 laptop (Dell Latitude), Android 10 tablet (Samsung S6 Lite) and an Android 6 phone (MotoE2). I can connect Bluetooth devices to all of these---namely, my headphones and wireless speaker.

However, I am unable to get any of the three to connect to each other. They all pair successfully initially, but then I am unable to connect. *Occasionally* the laptop will say it's connected to the tablet, but the tablet does not agree.

I would like to be able to use the Bluetooth connectivity for a variety of reasons. I am stumped as to why it is not working.
My drivers in Windows 10 are up-to-date and there are no warnings in Device Manager.

Comment: Because the computer and tablet is not a headset or other device they do no see a reason to have a permanent connection. If you need to transfer something via Bluetooth or use it as a modem then you need to configure tethering on the device with the connection to be shared which should allow for a more permanent connection based on what you want to do. Without knowing what you are actually doing it is hard to say why you are seeing this behaviour. You are trying to get them to "connect" to do what exactly? Bluetooth is not normally a shared connection like WiFi.

Comment: Ah, I did not know that. Thank you, that's very informative! I would like to either transfer files between the devices, use one's internet access on the other or project from one device to the other (eg using Windows Connect)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless the devices have a specific reason to stay connected, such as playing music or sharing an Internet connection, then they will not bother staying connected.  This is a feature of the "service" based nature of Bluetooth technology.

In order to send a file you would simply select the file on an Android device (in whatever file manager you have) and then "share" it. Then select "Bluetooth" as the program to share to, which will allow you to push the file at another device via Bluetooth. This will connect to the other device, transfer the file and then disconnect. The same will happen on a PC, you "send" a file, not share it as you would over WiFi.

In order to share an Internet connection then you need the device to be set up to share its connection.  On Samsung Android mobile phones you will need to go to **Settings -> Connections -> Mobile Hotspot and Tethering** and you will see an option to enable Bluetooth Tethering. Enabling that should allow another device to "see" its Internet connection and your computer should be able to connect to it. A computer will then be able to connect *through* the phone.

To share your computers Internet connection over Bluetooth the settings are at **Windows Settings -> Network & Internet -> Mobile hotspot.** where you will be able to choose to share over Bluetooth or WiFi and then tell your phone to connect to it. The phone will then connect *through* the computer.

Bluetooth connections are not "peer to peer", they are based on a client-server style. A server provides a service such as an Internet connection or an audio speaker and a client program connects to that service to use it. If you don't have that service set up to begin with then the devices won't have a reason to stay connected.

Both devices also must support that connection. If you have a device that doesn't support sharing its Internet connection then no amount of work on the client will make it see it on the other device. Again, it will see nothing to connect to and simply disconnect.

File sharing is a slightly special case where the receiver acts as a server to "accept" a file.

For sharing other features from one device to another you will first have to find out how to enable that feature being shared on the device.

Comment: This is extremely informative, thank you! Things still aren't working quite as I desire, but I'll play with them a little more. If needed, I'll post a separate question regarding the specific problem---this question was a general "why don't they connect", which you have answered very well, rather than "why can't I share/project/etc in this particular circumstance"

Comment: Fair enough, it makes sense to have a more specific "how do I connect these two things to do X" per task than a whole raft within one question. Bear in mind though that Bluetooth is a very limited protocol designed for low power and as such has low bandwidth limits of about 2Mbps. It has a "high speed" mode that actually uses a connection similar to an ad-hoc WiFi connection but doesn't seem widely supported as devices that *can* do that are more likely to just use WiFi in the first place.

Comment: I see, thank you. Would something like projecting tablet to PC probably just use WiFi instead, for example?

Comment: Yes, Miracast and other solutions almost exclusively use WiFi. Some solutions can also work over USB, like Samsung Dex. Streaming high resolution video, even compressed, is far beyond what bluetooth is capable of.

Answer (score 4):

For transferring files between Windows 10 devices, you may use the new
Nearby Sharing feature, available since the April 2018 Update.
The Microsoft article
[Share things with nearby devices in Windows 10](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/share-things-with-nearby-devices-in-windows-10-0efbfe40-e3e2-581b-13f4-1a0e9936c2d9)
shows how to share any file through Explorer *right-click > Share*,
or for images via the Photos app.

Android devices have their own Nearby Share feature between them (but not with PC).
See the article
[How to Share Files Between Android Devices With Nearby Share](https://www.pcmag.com/how-to/how-to-share-files-between-android-devices-with-nearby-share).

There are other file-transfer methods possible between differing device architectures,
if all the devices connect to the same router and are all on the same
local network.
For example, one device might install an SSH server and the other an SSH client.
On Windows I like the free [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/download.php)
utility as client.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. It doesn't answer the overall question, though. Rather, it addresses _one_ part of what I want to use connectivity for, but not others, so I won't mark it as accepted